# how include my local jar to maven?

Tags: java, maven

the question is:

i start a local lib to collect some common utils in it.

then i use eclipse m2e to run as Maven Install, and it truely generate the jar into my local cached repos dir.

and now, i want to use that lib as a dependency in my project, i just type the dependency xml as the other (like spring etc.).

but it just can load that lib in the maven dependencies libs.

I search the web and find that systemPath could work, but i don' t like this way. how can i use my local jar in a same way?

Comment: You cab install that jar in local maven repo. Once done successfully you can inject it as a normal dependency.

Comment: and another way is to have nexus server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a (non-Maven) build and:

- install the JAR in your local "repo" directory,
- manually upload it your group / corporate repository, or
- install it in a so-called "internal repository" that you manage by hand: see http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html.

(I have even resorted to using an "internal repository" that was part of the project's version control check-out; i.e. putting the JAR into version control.)

But I think that the *best* approach would be to Mavenize the build for the utility JAR, and handle it just like your main Maven projects.

Answer (score 2):

Install it into your repository. Either local (`mvn install`) or run repository software like Artifactory, Archiva or Nexus. http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

Answer (score 0):

Use goal install-file .
Like , mvn [install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html).